# NSStreamDelegate reading asynchronous data

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, stream

OK. So there is an exceptional case I have to handle for NSStreamDelegate implementation.

The process is the following:

1- a COMMAND data is written to the output stream to trigger the other end

2- The other end, starts putting data for the input stream BUT asynchronously, meaning that the first part of the data is received at the beginning then a couple of seconds later, the rest of the data comes in.

3- After all the data is received, the server will NOT send any data but the connection remains open. (input stream status = Open (2))

4- After couple of minutes, the server ends the connection (input stream status = 5) and NSStreamEventEndEncountered is triggered.

**SendRequest class**

```
- (void)sendSecondRequest {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream = nil;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = nil;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)self.SOMEServer, self.SOMEPort, &readStream, &writeStream);
    self.inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    self.outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [self.inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [self.outputStream setDelegate:self];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:[kSecondCall dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.inputStream open];
    [self.outputStream open];
    [self.outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            if (aStream == self.inputStream) {
                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                NSInteger len = [self.inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0) {
                    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                    [gOutput appendString:output];
                }
            }
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host");
            [aStream close];
            [aStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            aStream = nil;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)disconnectSocket {
    [self.inputStream close];
    [self.inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.outputStream close];
    [self.outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.inputStream setDelegate:nil];
    [self.outputStream setDelegate:nil];
    self.inputStream = nil;
    self.outputStream = nil;
}
```

The **gOutput** variable is a global variable that I use to read and store input stream.

The problem is that since the data's first part comes immediately and then the rest comes in asynchronously, I can not handle the moment when there is no more data available.

In other words, how can I know if the server is done sending data and I should start processing it?

Answer (score 0):

Server sends a terminator sequence at the end.  when the client detects this terminator, it starts to process....